# Asymptotic complexity in python for O-Upper

Tags: python, complexity-theory, infinite-loop, notin, code-complexity

I'm studying the complexity of functions in python, and I have this two there Im not sure, one because I think it's infinite loop and second is the not in method build in on python:

1- The function f1 receives a positive integer n and a list v. v is larger than n.

```
def f1(n, v): 
   b=n*n
   s=0
   while b > 1: 
      s += v[n]
      s += b
      b -= 2 
   return s
```

2- The function f2 receives a dictionary d and a list l.

```
def f2(d,l): 
   r = []
   for x in l:
      if x not in d:
         r.append(x)
return r
```

I am studying them on "O-Upper", O. ex O (n ^ 2) is quadratic.
What is the complexity of this two functions?

Comment: You're not really asking a question.  What is it you want to know?

Comment: What is the complexity of this two functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f1` contains a loop that executes *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* times, and it performs only constant-time operations. Like EnderShadow8 explained, this makes your function *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

`f2` contains a loop that executes *O(n)* times, where `n` is the length of `l`.
Since `d` is a Python dictionary, checking if `x` is in `d` runs in [amortized *O(1)* time](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). This is because a dictionary does not in practice iterate through all its elements to find `x`, but rather it uses an underlying hash map data structure.
Appending to a list is also in practice a constant-time operation in Python.
Therefore, `f2` is actually an *O(n)* time function.

Comment: @Bertgur Thank you very much, my teacher explained that to me too, I just forgot it. Thanks

Comment: @AntónioRochaGonçalves No problem.This demonstrates the importance of using the right data structure for the right task. *O(n^2)* algorithms quickly become unpractical as the input scales.